# column with previous result

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I'm working with R

WHAT I HAVE:

```
      ID_1     ID_2      Date        x_1        y_2     
1      12       3     2011-12-21       15        10     
2      12       13    2011-12-22       50        40     
3      3        12    2011-12-22       20        30     
4      15       13    2011-12-23       30        20     
...
and so on
```

TARGET:

```
      ID_1     ID_2      Date        x_1        y_2     XX_1      YY_2
1      12       3     2011-12-21       15        10      0         0
2      12       13    2011-12-22       50        40      15        0
3      3        12    2011-12-22       20        30      10        50
4      15       13    2011-12-23       30        20      0         40
...
and so on
```

I want to see in `XX_1` and in `YY_2` the values from the columns `x_1` and `y_2` corresponding to the previous values of `ID_1` and `ID1_2` in or `"0"` in case of no value is available before that date. I don't know how to handle the fact that different values could be in `ID_1` and `ID_2` (like IDs 3 and 12 in the example).

@Ekatef
ID1 AND ID2 (find match of the whole ID row, even if the order of IDs is switched):

```
      ID_1     ID_2      Date        x_1        y_2     XX_1      YY_2
1      12       3     2011-12-21       15        10      0         0
2      12       13    2011-12-22       50        40      0         0
3      3        12    2011-12-22       20        30      10        15
4      15       13    2011-12-23       30        20      0         0
5      12       13    2011-12-23       10        5       50        40
```

Comment: I've read this post at least 4 times and I am struggling to understand what you are asking for. I was trying to figure out how to produce `XX_1` and `YY_1`, but to no avail. You need to explain what you mean more. This really is confusing. It's probably just an issue that I don't understand.

Comment: row2, XX_1 is 15 because the "last" result of ID1 12 is 15 (x_1). In YY_2 is 0 because there are no records about id 13.
row3, ID1 is 3, previous value of 3 is 10 (y_2) so in XX_1 the value is 10.
and so on. 

the number in the name columns is referred to the ID position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to copy the previous value for an `ID` (if any) to the appropriate new column.

This can solved by *reshaping multiple columns simultaneously* from wide to long format, finding the previous value by shifting / lagging, and reshaping back to wide format:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, rn := .I]
long <- melt(DF, id.vars = c("rn", "Date"), measure.vars = patterns("^ID", "^x|y"),
             value.name = c("ID", "value"))
long[order(Date), previous := shift(value, fill = 0), by = ID]
dcast(long, rn + Date ~ variable, value.var = c("ID", "value", "previous"))
```

> ```
>    rn       Date ID_1 ID_2 value_1 value_2 previous_1 previous_2
> 1:  1 2011-12-21   12    3      15      10          0          0
> 2:  2 2011-12-22   12   13      50      40         15          0
> 3:  3 2011-12-22    3   12      20      30         10         50
> 4:  4 2011-12-23   15   13      30      20          0         40
> ```

Alternatively, the final call to `dcast()` can be replaced by an *update while joining*:

```
DF[long, on = .(rn), 
   c("XX_1", "YY_2") := .(previous[variable == 1L], previous[variable == 2L])][
     , rn := NULL]
DF
```

> ```
>    ID_1 ID_2       Date x_1 y_2 XX_1 YY_2
> 1:   12    3 2011-12-21  15  10    0    0
> 2:   12   13 2011-12-22  50  40   15    0
> 3:    3   12 2011-12-22  20  30   10   50
> 4:   15   13 2011-12-23  30  20    0   40
> ```

which reproduces exactly OP's expected result.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "i      ID_1     ID_2      Date        x_1        y_2     
  1      12       3     2011-12-21       15        10     
  2      12       13    2011-12-22       50        40     
  3      3        12    2011-12-22       20        30     
  4      15       13    2011-12-23       30        20  ",
  drop = 1L
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the target ID should be looked up from the left to the right and from the bottom to the top in all the rows strictly above the given ID value. I would write the function to **find the coordinates of the preceded ID** like that

```
# find the indices of the preceded ID value
# @id_matrix == your_data_frame[, c("ID_1", "ID_2")]
# [@i_of_row, @i_of_col] are the coordinates of the considered ID
# i_of_row > 1
FindPreviousID <- function(id_matrix, i_of_row, i_of_col) {
    shorten_matrix <- id_matrix[1:(i_of_row - 1),,drop = FALSE]
    rev_ind <- match(table = rev(t(shorten_matrix)), 
        x = ids[i_of_row,i_of_col], nomatch = NA_real_)
    n_row_found <- floor((length(shorten_matrix) - rev_ind)/2) + 1
    n_col_found <- (length(shorten_matrix) - rev_ind) %% ncol(shorten_matrix) + 1
    return(c(row = n_row_found, col = n_col_found))
}
```

...and use it to **calculate XX_1 and YY2**

```
# emulate the original dataframe
ID_1 <- c(12,12,3,15,16,3)
ID_2<-c(3,13,12,13,17,15)
ids <- cbind(ID_1, ID_2) # IDs columns
x1 <- c(15, 50, 20, 30, 51, 60)
y2 <- c(10, 40, 30, 20, 53, 62)
vars <- cbind(x1, y2) # x&y columns
# assuming that the first XX_1 & YY_2 should be always 0 
indices_XX  <- sapply(FUN = function(i) FindPreviousID(id_matrix = ids, i_of_col = 1, i), 
    X = seq(along.with = ids[, 1])[-1])
indices_YY  <- sapply(FUN = function(i) FindPreviousID(id_matrix = ids, i_of_col = 2, i), 
    X = seq(along.with = ids[, 1])[-1])
#  construct XX and YY columns
XX_column <- c(NA, vars[t(indices_XX)])
XX_column[is.na(XX_column)] <- 0
YY_column <- c(NA, vars[t(indices_YY)])
YY_column[is.na(YY_column)] <- 0
```

Hope, that helps :)

**Upd** If you are interested to find a pair of IDs instead of the single ID, the function should be redesigned. One of the possible solutions looks like this

```
FindPreviousIDsPair <- function(id_matrix, i_of_row) {
shorten_matrix <- id_matrix[1:(i_of_row - 1),,drop = FALSE]
string_to_search_for <- id_matrix[i_of_row, ]
string_to_search_for_sorted <- 
    string_to_search_for[order(string_to_search_for)]
found_rows_boolean <- sapply(FUN = function(i) all(shorten_matrix[i, 
    order(shorten_matrix[i, ])] == 
    string_to_search_for_sorted), X = 1:(i_of_row - 1)) 
found_row_n <- ifelse(any(found_rows_boolean),
    max(which(found_rows_boolean)), NA_real_)
found_col_of_DI1 <- ifelse(any(found_rows_boolean), 
    match(string_to_search_for[1], shorten_matrix[found_row_n, ]), NA_real_)
found_col_of_DI2 <- ifelse(any(found_rows_boolean), 
    match(string_to_search_for[2], shorten_matrix[found_row_n, ]), NA_real_)    
return(c(found_row_n, found_col_of_DI1, found_col_of_DI2))
}
```

Application of the redisigned look-up function to calculate XX and YY

```
indices_of_vars  <- sapply(FUN = function(i) FindPreviousIDsPair(id_matrix = 
     ids, i), X = seq(along.with = ids[, 1])[-1])
indices_XX <- indices_of_vars[1:2, ]
indices_YY <- indices_of_vars[c(1, 3), ]
XX_column <- c(NA, vars[t(indices_XX)])
XX_column[is.na(XX_column)] <- 0
YY_column <- c(NA, vars[t(indices_YY)])
YY_column[is.na(YY_column)] <- 0
```

Comment: I'll give it a try this week, thanx in advance

Comment: it works like a charm! thanx a lot, now i know how to do task like that. I never tought about script a function. 
+1

Comment: I tried to undestand your code but some lines are nosense for me. I hope you can solve my doubts about how it works.

1) n_row_found and n_col_found. why u use floor and divided by 2, +1? I didn't get what is doing.

2) Let's say that I want use the same script for another purpose: do the same only when the elemnt in id1 and id2 (same row) occurs above,
of course same if same element but inverted in column id1 and id2.

Comment: Thank you for a feedback! 1) The calculations of the `n_row_found`, `n_col_found` are intended to convert a "linear" index `rev_ind` of the found element in the transformed `shorten_matrix` to a pair of indices in the original `shorten_matrix`. The trick is using different ways of R subsetting. Section 3 of Wickman's "Advanced R" was extremely helpful for me to master these issues. The formulas to convert between a "linear" index and to a pair of indices was discussed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4452039/8465924).

Comment: 2) I do not not quite understand what do you want to change. Is it a correspondence between`lD_1`/`lD_2` and `x_1`/`y_2`? Could you please give an example to clarify?

Comment: 1) thanx, now is more clear (and I will buy the book, thank you) 2) I want to change the condition. Not anymore "add previous result of ID1 or ID2" but "add previous result of ID1 AND ID2". Example added in the main question above.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification! Unfortunately, match() is intended to be used to search the single value only. So, this another purpose requires some modifications of the FindPreviousID(), which I have added to my answer.

Comment: I tought was more simple than that, I didn't want to waste your time on a different task that you already solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry, it was valuable experience for me, too. I'm quite sure that redesign of Uwe's approach would be much simpler. Our joined efforts have given a good example how data.tables over-perform data frames.