# Counter of previous matches

Tags: r, database, dataframe, counter

I have found a lot of material about counting a value in table, but my goal is little different and I havent found any source.

This is my data

```
       ID_1     ID_2      Date        RESULT      
1      12       3     2011-12-21       0         
2      12       13    2011-12-22       0         
3      3        12    2011-12-22       1           
4      15       13    2011-12-23       0                 
5      12       13    2011-12-23       1                 
5      13       15    2011-12-23       1                  
6      3        12    2011-12-23       0            
7      12       13    2011-12-23       0
```

TARGET

```
      ID_1     ID_2      Date        RESULT    H2H_ID1    H2H_ID2   
1      12       3     2011-12-21       0           0         0
2      12       13    2011-12-22       0           0         0
3      3        12    2011-12-22       1           1         0
4      15       13    2011-12-23       0           0         0       
5      12       13    2011-12-23       1           0         1       
5      13       15    2011-12-23       1           1         0        
6      3        12    2011-12-23       0           2         0  
7      12       13    2011-12-23       0           1         1     
...
and so on
```

In `RESULT`, 0 is a match won by `id2`, 1 when is won by `id1`.
I need 2 columns (`h2h_id1`, `h2h_id2`) that count the match previously won by the same players (id1 and id2), the traditional head-to-head.

I'll make an example. Row 3.
`ID1=3` and  `ID2=12`.
The row where id 3 and id 12  had a previous match is row1, and the winner of the match is `id2` (`result=0`).
So in the row 3 I want to read `1` in the `H2H_ID1`.
In row 6, same conditions, 2 matches with same ids and same result.

In another post, for a similiar tastk, ([column with previous result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968516/column-with-previous-result))
they gave me this code to find only 1 match before (and without sum) but maybe could help.

```
# emulate the original dataframe
ID_1 <- c(12,12,3,15,16,3)
ID_2<-c(3,13,12,13,17,15)
ids <- cbind(ID_1, ID_2) # IDs columns
x1 <- c(15, 50, 20, 30, 51, 60)
y2 <- c(10, 40, 30, 20, 53, 62)
vars <- cbind(x1, y2) # x&y columns

FindPreviousIDsPair <- function(id_matrix, i_of_row) {
shorten_matrix <- id_matrix[1:(i_of_row - 1),,drop = FALSE]
string_to_search_for <- id_matrix[i_of_row, ]
string_to_search_for_sorted <- 
    string_to_search_for[order(string_to_search_for)]
found_rows_boolean <- sapply(FUN = function(i) all(shorten_matrix[i, 
    order(shorten_matrix[i, ])] == 
    string_to_search_for_sorted), X = 1:(i_of_row - 1)) 
found_row_n <- ifelse(any(found_rows_boolean),
    max(which(found_rows_boolean)), NA_real_)
found_col_of_DI1 <- ifelse(any(found_rows_boolean), 
    match(string_to_search_for[1], shorten_matrix[found_row_n, ]), NA_real_)
found_col_of_DI2 <- ifelse(any(found_rows_boolean), 
    match(string_to_search_for[2], shorten_matrix[found_row_n, ]), NA_real_)    
return(c(found_row_n, found_col_of_DI1, found_col_of_DI2))
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you computing something like an Elo rating?

Comment: For the Elo rating I already used the package "PlayerRatings".

Comment: You sholud try to study the others (`elo` or `EloRating`), because I suspect you may find a function that yet implements your rules