# How to get a vector by indexing a matrix with pair of vectors?

Tags: r, arrays, indexing, array-broadcasting

Given two vectors that are the components of a list of indices, how do I index a matrix by them **pairwise**?  If I just use them as is, I get the cartesian product (as is consistent with fancy indexing in other languages):

```
> x
           [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.4636395 0.7937225  0.81670694
[2,] -1.0591770 0.7515119  1.31597748
[3,] -0.5215888 1.2026196 -0.03518676
> x[c(1,2), c(1, 1)]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.4636395  0.4636395
[2,] -1.0591770 -1.0591770
```

while I really want

```
> c(x[1, 1], x[2, 1])
[1]  0.4636395 -1.0591770
```

In Julia, I can write rather concisely:

```
julia> x[CartesianIndex.([1, 2], [1, 1])] # not the same x here, but still 3x3
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.5815007881748451
 0.6563715338911154
```

In Matlab, I have been told that the equivalent of this is to convert manually to a linear index:

```matlab
x(sub2ind(A, [1, 2], [1, 1]))
```

How do I do that in R?

(This is actually a different question for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296902/1346276), but I really could not find the solution easily by searching. Especially no duplicate, even though I imagine it must be a common question.  That "R" is not a well-googleable keyword didn't help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Indexing" is usually called ["subsetting"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) in R.  And you have to subset by a *matrix* in this case.  Which can be constructed most easily by `cbind`ing the vectors together:

```
> cbind(c(1,2), c(1, 1))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
> x[cbind(c(1,2), c(1, 1))]
[1]  0.4636395 -1.0591770
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the value this question-answer pair provides. As usual, when considering subsetting, you should just study `help("[")`. It will answer (almost?) all such questions.

Comment: I consider myself a rather experienced programmer, and was not able to find this information without at least ten minutes of searching. Also not explicitely on SO. It's not that it is nowhere documented, but that it is not easily discoverable, IMO.

Comment: Your issue is that you call this operation "indexing". It's called "subsetting" in R.

Comment: This answer uses matrix subsetting. You could achieve the same with a vector: `x[c(1,2)]`